# Formatting Excel Cells through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

When you copy and paste from one excel sheet to another, you have the option to keep the source formatting or use current formatting. Is there an equivalent way to enforce this in VBA?

For example, I have:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Range(A2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("C7")
```

To copy a value from sheet1 (A2) to sheet2 (C7). Is there any way to use the format styles of C7 of sheet2, rather than saving the formatting from A2 of sheet1?

Comment: record a macro and look up the code

Comment: Just write the values directly, instead of relying on the `Copy` method: `Sheets("sheet2").Range("C7").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2").Value`  Should be faster, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Copy` with `Destination` copies all. Using `Copy/PasteSpecial`, you can select what you want to copy.

```
xlPasteType: 
xlPasteAll (default), 
xlPasteFormats, 
xlPasteFormulas, 
PasteFormulasAndNumberFormats, 
xlPasteValues, 
xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats 
(more)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help dcromley, I've just started learning VBA and I didn't realize this was apparently such a poor question. I will be sure to document all the stuff I went through to even get to this point in the future.

Comment: @user2321081 - best to you.